# World world world world

Tags: word, wordplay, rebus

Psychology teacher posted this riddle on the board today: the word "world" written four times. All the "worlds" are stacked on top of one another.

```
WORLD  
WORLD  
WORLD  
WORLD
```

Comment: Do you have any more information you can provide to us? Not really sure what you're asking exactly. And welcome to PSE

Comment: Thank you. Is riddle the right term? Brain teaser? Finding hidden meaning. Anyway, that's all the information I have. Edited the question a bit.

Comment: it is rebus I think?

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: Rebus is for image based puzzles, where we deduce a word or phrase from an image, there isn't any image here as far as I can tell. Word/Wordplay may be more appropriate

Comment: @n_palum you're actually wrong there, a rebus can be anything

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil "A visual puzzle that involves trying to figure out a word or phrase from an image that gives clues to parts of the word or phrase." - Am I missing something? Image or visual, regardless this is just wordplay

Comment: @n_palum the 'visual' can just be an arrangement of words. I might need to tweak that, its not actually that accurate. I'll ping you some examples of word rebuses in chat

Comment: I'm gonna bet that the point of this assignment is to see how people interpret it. My guess is that the teacher has no 'correct' solution. Not that this is a bad puzzle. I'm just betting that it is a psychological trick. The teacher wants to demonstrate how people can interpret the world differently.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is

> **For all the world** (or just *for the world*)

Because

> There are four worlds, giving 'for' then 'all the world'

Comment: I don't get it. Is this a common phrase? I have been British English my whole life and never heard it.

Comment: I've heard it in sentences such as "I wouldn't give you away for all the world" Also Google's NGram for that phrase: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=For+all+the+world&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CFor%20all%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CFor%20all%20the%20world%3B%2Cc1

Comment: @theonlygusti yes its a [common idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+all+the+world)

Comment: @GrantDavis that's true actually. Like this though, as a standalone phrase, it's completely alien to me. I can't imagine that this was ever the intended answer.

Comment: @theonlygusti surely you must have heard it at one point? Its pretty common. Used two ways: 1: I wouldn't do X for all the world, 2: Someone looked for all the world as if they were about to do X. In 1, it means I wouldn't do something for anything, in 2 it means you'd bet the whole world they were about to do something, they really look like they are about to

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil "Like this though, as a standalone phrase, it's completely alien to me."

Answer (score 9):

Teacher gave the answer. It is

> World Series

Because

> It is a series of the word 'world'.

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit tenuous. I prefer my answer more :P

Comment: Haha, to be honest I do too @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: At least draw connecting lines to show them in order or something?

Answer (score 7):

I think the teacher is indicating the following:

> Many people see the *world* differently.

Why I think this is:

> First off, the teacher is teaching psychology and such an answer seems right up their alley. Secondly, I can demonstrate several answers with little difficulty. The puzzle still makes sense but the 'trick' is to see past the riddle itself.

1.

> 4 worlds = world series

2.

> For the world

3.

> Layered world

4.

> The Matrix (pun on the mathematical definition)

5.

> Flat worlds

Final thoughts

> I cannot choose any one of these over the other. In fact, everything indicates they are equally valid. This doesn't make the puzzle unclear. It just adds another layer of depth to this very intriguing rebus.

Comment: So the solution itself is essentially "too broad," in other words?
Perfect!

Comment: I really like this answer. It's an interesting take on the deeper meaning of the puzzle. I also like #4.

Comment: @humn that is exactly what I mean. :-)

Comment: @landen Thank you. Number 4 was my personal favorite as well. If I had to pick one to submit, I would personally use that one.

Comment: @laden can also : worlds under world